# Boot on charge for Huawei g70

Tags: boot, huawei

Can somebody help me on how to make Huawei G730 to boot when connected to the charger? I've founs a tool to do this on Samsung that doesn't work on this phone.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

1. Install [ADB and fastboot](http://developer.android.com/tools/help/adb.html). If you already have the Android SDK, you can find these tools in dir_to_sdk/sdk/platform-tools/. If you don't have the SDK, here is a [direct link to Minimal ADB and Fastboot (for Windows)](http://fs1.d-h.st/download/00145/IRd/adb-setup-1.4.2.exe).
2. Install your device drivers if applicable.
3. Run the following code from your ADB/fastboot directory:

   ```
   fastboot oem unlock
   fastboot oem off-mode-charge 0
   fastboot oem lock
   fastboot reboot
   ```

*Note: On certain devices, performing `fastboot oem unlock` may perform a factory reset.*